# Finding topology book with great exercises

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a student self-studying topology. Recently I found Janich's book and its content was wonderful, except that it has no problems.

So I am finding supplementary material that has some challenging exercises that can help me understand the topics.

I don't like a verbose reference-style book. I don't want the book to have too many(more than 30) exercises on a chapter.

For example, baby Rudin would perfectly meet my requirements, but it is not a topology book.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Stephen Willard, General Topology.

Comment: Viro et al . https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/viro.pdf